# WordPress post_status is future, manually added

Tags: mysql, post-status

My time zone is UTC+1. Now (and when the post creates the database): 2019-12-16 08:06:00

GMT (now): 2019-12-16 07:06:00

```
INSERT INTO `wp_posts` (

`ID`,
`post_author`,
`post_date`,
`post_date_gmt`,
`post_content`,
`post_title`,
`post_excerpt`,
`post_status`,
`comment_status`,
`ping_status`,
`post_password`,
`post_name`,
`to_ping`,
`pinged`,
`post_modified`,
`post_modified_gmt`,
`post_content_filtered`,
`post_parent`,
`guid`,
`menu_order`,
`post_type`,
`post_mime_type`,
`comment_count`

) VALUES (

NULL, -- `ID`
'1', -- `post_author`
'2019-12-16 08:30:00', -- `post_date`
'2019-12-16 07:30:00', -- `post_date_gmt`
'Test.', -- `post_content`
'Test', -- `post_title`
'', -- `post_excerpt`
'future', -- `post_status`
'open', -- `comment_status`
'open', -- `ping_status`
'', -- `post_password`
'', -- `post_name`
'', -- `to_ping`
'', -- `pinged`
'2019-12-16 08:06:00', -- `post_modified`
'2019-12-16 07:06:00', -- `post_modified_gmt`
'', -- `post_content_filtered`
'0', -- `post_parent`
'', -- `guid`
'0', -- `menu_order`
'post', -- `post_type`
'', -- `post_mime_type`
'0' -- `comment_count`

);
```

I would like to see this post at 2019-12-16 08:30:00 (GMT: 2019-12-16 07:30:00).

After 08:30:00 (GMT: 07:30:00) the post_status is future, but why not publish?

[image]

What is the problem?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

> Several WordPress core features, such as checking for updates and
>   publishing scheduled post, utilize WP-Cron.

The problem is likely you had no visits to your site since the time the post is scheduled to.

> Scheduling errors could occur if you schedule a task for 2:00PM and no
>   page loads occur until 5:00PM.

Source: "[What is WP-Cron](https://developer.wordpress.org/plugins/cron/#what-is-wp-cron)" from Developer Resources.

You can use some plugins to check and log what does WP-Cron do or don't do.

But better solution is to completely disable WP-Cron in the `wp-config.php` and configure the regular system cron. You'll get the performance improvement coincidently.

Comment: I visited the site many times.

Comment: Edited the answer.